# Empty Heap Dump after OutOfMemoryException

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection, heap-dump

I'm getting an `OutOfMemoryException` on Tomcat7 and openjdk 1.8.0_162.

A heap dump is being created but when analyzing with Memory Analyzer (MAT) no problems are found and the tool reports lots of free heap space.

I'm aware what GC overhead limit exceeded means I just cannot figure out what is being done at that time. The heap dump would normally show me what objects taking up so much space.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Dumping heap to /var/log/tomcat7/java_pid13747.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [4694238678 bytes in 50.790 secs]
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

some log lines from the `gc.log`:

```
... 
2018-04-17T10:12:29.208+0200: 6436.957: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 465920K->464244K(931840K)] [ParOldGen: 2796166K->2796166K(2796544K)] 3262086K->3260410K(3728384K), [Metaspace: 233392K->233392K(1306624K)], 6.6466544 secs] [Times: user=25.17 sys=0.03, real=6.65 secs]
2018-04-17T10:12:35.866+0200: 6443.614: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 465920K->464395K(931840K)] [ParOldGen: 2796166K->2796165K(2796544K)] 3262086K->3260560K(3728384K), [Metaspace: 233396K->233396K(1306624K)], 6.6379297 secs] [Times: user=25.01 sys=0.06, real=6.64 secs]
2018-04-17T10:12:42.516+0200: 6450.265: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 465920K->464702K(931840K)] [ParOldGen: 2796165K->2796165K(2796544K)] 3262085K->3260867K(3728384K), [Metaspace: 233403K->233400K(1306624K)], 6.9424274 secs] [Times: user=25.14 sys=0.08, real=6.94 secs]
...
```

MAT chart (grey is free space...):
[image]

How to approach this?

I suspect that some resource heavy operation is being done but the heap dump is empty...

Comment: Try running with a stack sampling profiler. The samples shortly before the OOME occurs are probably the interesting ones. Or use an allocation profiler.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to reproduce this locally, happens only in production.

Comment: profilers that are non-invasive enough to be used in production exist.